# I have an odd field with a purple background, mentioning HTML-codes to use while leaving comments

Tags: comments, html, blog

I'm very new to this whole deal with creating websites and wordpress and all, so if there's anything basic knowledge I've missed, then I probably missed it. That saying;
I have a weird issue. I want to let visitors have the ability to leave comments on blogposts I do, but the field looks like this; https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUyqq.jpg (I hope an imgur link is ok)

I'd like to have only the "leave a reply", the text about email adress, the comment section itself, name/mail/website fields and the checkbox and the "post comment" button. I dont want that purple box with HTML-codes there - I dont even know where the heck it came from.

Does *anyone* know what I can do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://wpbeaches.com/add-html-tags-and-attributes-back-into-comments-in-wordpress/) says that feature was removed from Wordpress a long time ago, so you may have a theme or plugin which has put it back.

You can try using the same filter to remove it again. To use the filter you need to add this to your functions.php file:

```
function remove_comment_prompt( $defaults ) {
    return "";
}

add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'remove_comment_prompt', 999, 1);
```